# How can Service Provider reinforce password prompt at IdP server?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

SAML 2.0 with the "POST" Binding: Is there any way for Service Provider to ask IdP for user re-authentication for the specific request? I mean first time web user enters login/password, than it stores some sort of cookie in a browser memory so that it remembers the user and does not ask him for password again next time inside the session. I want SP be able to enforce re-authentication which means a command to ask user for password again

The only similar thing I found (`ForceAuthn`) and it does not help me:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest ForceAuthn="true" ... >
```

According to documentation `ForceAuthn` is exactly what I need, but for some reason Microsoft ADFS 2.0 completely ignores it not asking user for password

Comment: Force authn is the way to go, and from what I can read in ADFS docs, it is supported. Do you det any messages? I gues you dont have access to the ADFS logs?

Comment: No, I do not get any messages, and I believe I can get access to its logs on Monday, I'll let you know if there is anything valuable in them

Comment: How is the user being authenticated at ADFS (IDP)? If it's Kerberos or NTLM, I think the browser will silently re-authenticate the user and the user won't have any interaction again with the IDP until the browser is closed/reopened (NTLM only). It's really dependent on the IDP Authentication mechanism of the user and if ForceAuthn is supported.

Comment: I have not found anything interesting in logs. 
Yes, it is Kerberos, but first time ADFS asks user for login/password with Windows native popup window, not a web page. Still for me it sounds like lack of ForceAuth support in case of Kerberos/NTLM authentication. Is there any way to override this behavior?

Comment: Kerb should be silent so it sounds like NTLM if you are seeing a BASIC Auth prompt. Depending on the browser you may be able to control the auto-submit of the cached NTLM creds in the browser on the subsequent attempts but I believe the behavior you are seeing is by design with Kerb/NTLM.

Answer (score 3):

ADFS' default behavior to login a user on IdP side is 401 (NTLM) challenge, and all main stream browsers will cache user's id/pw input. Even though you specify "ForceAuthn=\"true\"", it wont help since the client side browser will send your cached id/pw again.

There is a way to change the default behavior on ADFS login strategy to adopt html form login. Supposing you are installing ADFS in default location, you can find c:\inetpub\adfs\ls\web.config. And there is `<localAuthenticationTypes>` element, and make sure you put `<add name="Forms" page="FormsSignIn.aspx" />` as the first element in it. Also you can customize the login form page as you like.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled in similar issues with the ForceAuthn parameter and ADFS.

Specifically requiring an ACR in combination with the ForceAuthn attribute seems to do the trick for me:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest ForceAuthn="true" [...]>
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
        </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
    [...]
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Which is actually the exact meaning of the request I meant to send to ADFS:

> Ignore your authentication context and ensure the user's password is
>   provided.